# Remove a substring from a filename with Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell, rename

In a deployment szenario, I need to rename config files. There are config files for every environment (Dev.Test, Dev.Prod, Integration, Prod). For example a web.config would be called web.Dev.Test.config if it was for the Dev.Test environment. On the target machine, I need to rename the files back to their original name (i.e. from web.Dev.Test.config to web.config) with Powershell.

```
$test = "web.Dev.Prod.config"
$environment = $test | Select-String -Pattern ".*\.(?<environment>(Dev.Test|Dev.Prod|Prod|Integration))\.config" | select -expand Matches | foreach {$_.groups["environment"].value} 
if ($test -match "Dev.Prod")
{
  $environment = "Dev.Prod"
}
$environment
$newFileName = $test.Remove($test.IndexOf($environment),$environment.Length + 1)
$newFileName
```

The problem I have with this is, that the Regex does not find the Dev.Prod evironment, but returns Prod instead. This is why I introduced the if statement. I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of renaming the files with Powershell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch out for greedy matching.  Modify your regex that starts `".*\.(?"` to `".*?\.(?"`.